# Odd behavor when selecting ADRecipient.DistinguishedName from Get-MailboxFolderPermission

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I'm pulling DistinguishedNames from a mailbox folder via:

```
$fldrPerm = Get-MailboxFolderPermission TestMailbox:\Folder
$fldrpermDN = @()
$fldrpermDN = foreach ($_ in $fldrperm){$_.User.ADRecipient.DistinguishedName}
```

The resulting array contains the DistinguishedNames when printed to screen, but using compare-object against another array it will error as null, also doing a foreach loop on the contents of $fldrpermDN, example:

```
foreach ($u in $fldrpermDN){get-mailbox $u}
```

will grab all the mailboxes in Exchange, not the mailboxes for the DN's contained in $fldrpermDN.

What would be causing this and how would I work around it? TIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace $_ with another name, it is null in foreach statements. $_ (current object) is only available inside script blocks.

```
$fldrpermDN = foreach ($folder in $fldrperm){$folder.User.ADRecipient.DistinguishedName}
```

Comment: I think the issue is acutally the Default and Anonymous id's that are pulled with the fldrPerm, if you foreach ($a in $fldrperDN){write-host $a} you can see two blank lines. I've tried adding  "| where {$folder.User.ADRecipient.DistinguishedName -ne "$null"}}" but it still grabs them.

Comment: foreach ($folder in $fldrperm){ if($folder.User.ADRecipient.DistinguishedName -ne $null) {$folder.User.ADRecipient.DistinguishedName}  }

Comment: `$FldrPermDN = $FldrPermDN | sort -Unique` does filter them out. Though I'm sure there is a more elegant way.